# Scaling random variables by negative factors?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Consider a normally distributed random variable $X$ with $\mu = 1$. Say we define another random variable $Y$ as $Y = 2X$. Then, we know that $E[Y] = 2E[X] = 2$. Intuitively, I understand this as stretching $X$ towards the right in a coordinate system.

Q1: Is this intuition correct, or is there some fundamental flaw in this intuition?

Now, say we define another random variable $Z = -2X$. Then, we know that $E[Z] = -2E[X] = -2$.

So, when we scale the distribution with +2, the mean shifts by one unit, 1 -> 2. However, when we scale the same distribution by -2, the mean is displaced by 3 units, 1 -> -2.

Since the variance in both cases is scaled by 4, does it means that the distribution is actually displaced? This does not make sense to me.

In the case where $\mu = 0$, the new mean after scaling still remains at 0, indicating that the distribution is stretched symmetrically irrespective of the sign.

I think I'm missing some fundamental concepts here. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is close, but not quite right. Doubling the variable stretches it **away from the y-axis**, not necessarily to the right. The parts of $X$ that are to the left of $0$ will be stretched to the *left* instead.

Negating the variable has the effect of *flipping* the variable over the $y$-axis. Note that a flip does not change the variance (i.e. spread) of a variable at all.